# Pathauto won't turn off on specific node

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I'm using pathauto, but I want to use a custom url alias on some of my nodes.

I edited my node, unchecked the `Generate automatic URL alias` checkbox and typed my custom url into the path box and clicked save.

This is the value I typed: `blog/blog.cfm/aid/496/Test-url-alias`

I don't get any errors when I save, but the url doesn't seem to take effect. When I edit the node again and go look at the url alias the `Generate automatic URL alias` checkbox is checked again. My value is still in the text field, but the field is disabled because the checkbox is checked meaning it should use an automatic alias.

Why won't my changes stick and use my custom url alias?

Comment: Did you delete the old alias?

Comment: No, I didn't, that's probably it. I've solved my problem in another way, so I can't test this one just yet, but I'll check it out.